# Plotly: how to change z-order of traces

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-express

I am having an issue with the order in which my Plotly.express and Plotly.graph_objects plots are showing up.  My scatter plot is plotting in front of my grey shaded continuous errors.
I have tried manually changing the order of the traces via updating each traces position in the fig.data array to no avail.
I want to force the scatter plot to the back/lowest z-level.

**Is there any way to get grey the shaded area in front/under the black line?**

[image: notice the gray shaded continuous error bars located behind the scatter plot]

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers.default='browser'

df3 = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
fig1 = px.scatter(df3, x="height_diff", y="flow_speed",
                 trendline="ols",
                 trendline_color_override = 'crimson',
                 template='plotly',
                 color_continuous_scale='Viridis',
                 color=np.random.randn(32145),
                 title='Linear Regression, HYCOM GOFS3.1, 2010-2020, 3hourly mean height difference vs. 3hourly mean Florida Current flow speed'
                 )



fig1.add_traces(px.line(df3, x="hgt_roll_avg", y="flow_roll_avg",color_discrete_sequence=['black']).data)
#fig2 = px.line(df3, x="hgt_roll_avg", y="flow_roll_avg",color_discrete_sequence=['black'])
#fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig.data, layout = fig1.layout)
fig1.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False,colorscale=dict(diverging = 'Viridis'))
fig1.add_traces([
    go.Scatter(
        name='Upper Bound',
        x=df3['hgt_roll_avg'],
        y=df3['flow_roll_avg']+df3['std'],
        mode='lines',
        marker=dict(color="#444"),
        line=dict(width=1),
        showlegend=False
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        name='Lower Bound',
       x=df3['hgt_roll_avg'],
       y=df3['flow_roll_avg']-df3['std'],
        marker=dict(color="#444"),
        line=dict(width=1),
        mode='lines',
        fillcolor='rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.3)',
        fill='tonexty',
        showlegend=False
    )
])
fig1.show()```
````

Comment: Traces are drawn in the order you add them to the fig **BUT** traces made with `plotly_express` generally are drawn with a different plotting engine than those made with `graph_objects`. The former are plotted with WebGL and are drawn *after* the traces made with the `graph_objects` library.

Comment: For reference, Plotly does not have z-orders, see [feature request: z-ordering parameter for traces #2345](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2345)

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:
REBUILD USING ONLY PLOTLY.GRAPH_OBJECT TRACES.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK9gK.png

```
fig1 = go.Figure()
fig1.add_traces([
    go.Scatter(
        name='scatter',
        x=df3['height_diff'],
        y=df3['flow_speed'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(color=np.random.randn(32145),colorscale='Viridis'),
        showlegend=False
    ),
    go.Scatter(
                  x=df4['height_diff'],
                  y=df4['bestfit'],
                  mode='lines',
                  marker=go.Marker(color='crimson'),
                  showlegend=False
                  )]) 

fig1.add_traces([
    go.Scatter(
        name='Upper Bound',
        x=df3['hgt_roll_avg'],
        y=df3['flow_roll_avg']+df3['std'],
        mode='lines',
        marker=dict(color="#444"),
        line=dict(width=1),
        showlegend=False
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        name='Lower Bound',
       x=df3['hgt_roll_avg'],
       y=df3['flow_roll_avg']-df3['std'],
        marker=dict(color="#444"),
        line=dict(width=1),
        mode='lines',
        fillcolor='rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.3)',
        fill='tonexty',
        showlegend=False
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=df3['hgt_roll_avg'],
        y=df3['flow_roll_avg'],
        mode='lines',
        marker=dict(color="black"),
        line=dict(width=1),
        showlegend=False
    )
])
fig1.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `go.Scattergl` instead of `px.scatter` for the trace you want to appear on top.

The reason you're getting the behavior where the trace draw order doesn't match what order you have in your code is because Plotly draws [regular traces](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter) first in the order in which they're added to the `fig` and **then** draws [traces made with the WebGL plotting engine](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scattergl/) (traces made via `plotly.express.scatter`) in the order in which they're added to the `fig`.

So, to be clear, any traces made using the WebGL engine will be draw *on top of* any regular traces, such as `go.Scatter`, even if such traces are added to `fig` *after* the WebGL traces.

In your case, this line is the culprit because it is drawn on top of your `go.Scatter` traces which are added later.

```py
fig1 = px.scatter(df3, x="height_diff", y="flow_speed", ...)
```

If you changed all your `go.Scatter` traces to `go.Scattergl` then the order you add each trace in your code will be preserved since every trace would be made with the WebGL plotting engine.

Alternatively, you can change your `px.scatter` to `go.Scatter` so that no traces are used with the WebGL plotting engine as you've shown in your answer.